# Updated PHP from 5.1 to 5.3.9 and accidentally uninstalled Plesk (Linux)

Tags: php, centos, centos5

I was updating PHP and when attempting to install 5.3.9, I got conflicts with 5.1 so I (rather stupidly) ran `yum remove php php-*` and I think that this removed the plesk plugin and I am able to access all the sites hosted, but not the actual plesk panel. The PSA folder is there in /usr/local/. When I tried reinstalling, and it returned `You have Plesk v 10.10.1 installed.`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the [Parallels autoinstaller](http://www.parallels.com/download/plesk/10/#centos) to re-install the missing package. It will probably detect it's missing and install it by itself, otherwise you might want to pick a random module/utility to install and it should detect the missing dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I did fix it, I did indeed run the installer that had been left in ~